# Flutter how to update the UI via setState after an await returns?

Tags: flutter, dart

So what I'm doing here is getting some stock data, and then once it comes in I want setState to refresh the UI on screen to reflect the correct price. But the price stays at 0 unless I hot reload the app. Any ideas?

```
void updateWatchList() async {
    StockService stockService = new StockService();
    for (WatchListItem item in watchListItems) {
      String symbol = item.symbol;
      var stockData = await stockService.getStockQuoteBySymbol(symbol);
      double newPrice = double.parse(stockData['Global Quote']['05. price']);
      setState(() { // for some reason setState is called before our await returns so the numbers only update after a hot reload
        // to update the numbers in our list
        item.price = newPrice;
      });
    }
  }
```

Here's the UI element:

```
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
     stream: Firestore.instance.collection('watchlists').document(uid).snapshots(), // hardcoded because getCurrentUser() doesn't work yet
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
       if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return new Center(
           child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
         );
       }
       if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         return new Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
       }
       else {
         var documents = snapshot.data.data; // get the data
         if (documents == null) {
           return new Center(
             child: Text("Add some stocks to your watchlist!"),
           );
         }
         var vals = documents.values; // values from data
         List symbols = vals.elementAt(0); // all our values are in an array on firestore called symbols which is at index 0

         for (int x = 0; x < symbols.length; x++) {
           watchListItems.add(
             WatchListItem(
               symbol: symbols.elementAt(x),
               price: 0.0,
             ),
           );
         }
         updateWatchList(); // call stock services to update our prices


         return new Center(
           child: ListView(
             children: watchListItems,
           ),
         );
       }
     },
   );
```

Comment: Why don't you use FutureBuilder ? and can you share the whole function code?

Comment: Check the edited code. I originally create the ui initialized to 0.0 since the data isn't ready yet. I could maybe replace the ListView with a FutureBuilder who's child is a ListView?

Comment: Try passing ***watchListItems*** as argument for updateWatchList() function.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference when that is passed in. watchListItems is in scope for the method

Answer (score 0):

Other people seem to be having this problem see if changing your `ListView` to a `ListView.builder` fixes your problem

```
 return new Center(
              child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: watchListItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => watchListItems[index],
           ),
         );
```

Comment: What value belongs where future() is? I would still need some code to get the snapshot no? My existing Firestore code gives an error if I try to put it as the future: parameter.

Comment: sorry I meant to change that code to reflect your code code earlier and was in a hurry and never did I have since updated it

Comment: It seems like this gets the circular progress indicator and that never goes away replaced with data for some reason. Even if I do a hot reload